# Wordpress - Integrating custom web application

Tags: php, python, wordpress, web-applications

I was tasked to create a file upload workflow that integrates with Wordpress.

I created a backend that is called via REST that does a lot of custom workflows. Thus, I cannot use the current plugins.

It is a single page application that accepts a file as well as some metadata.

My current dilemma:  I need to integrate this web application within Wordpress and have no clue where to start.

Comment: Please describe your app in more detail and what's your question? Do you use WordPress as backend or that's two different web app? You said that's a file upload workflow, so the user will upload the file through the single page app and the file will send to WordPress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After consulting with someone who's developed with Wordpress before, he recommended to build a plugin.  And since I have no experience with Wordpress, he helped me build it.  It was literally 3 lines of PHP.

Thank you all.